# Do Non-Static things from Static, C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, raspberry-pi3, windows-10-iot-core

I'm using c# to develop a small UWP app for Windows IoT that is installed on Raspberry pi 3. However, I want to this:

```
button.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
button1.Visibility = Visibility.Collpsed;
```

That code I want to keep it inside a static method :). I haven't found any helpful answer yet. I hope you guys will give me an easy and quick solution.

Comment: You cannot interact with non-static members from within a static method. If you want to do that, you'll need to pass an instance to the static method (or maintain a static reference to an instance in some other way), at which point you could probably just make the method non-static.

Comment: @CollinD -- Your comment is an answer, no?  Why post it as a comment instead of an answer?

Comment: It could work if `button` and `button1` are parameters of the static method. That is the only way.

Comment: @rory.ap It's not a particularly good answer, and I don't have the time just now to make it one.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to make that static you'll have to pass in the buttons

```
public static void DoStuff(Button button, Button button1)
{
    button.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    button1.Visibility = Visibility.Collpsed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a second option to Kevin's already sufficient answer, similar can be done with extension methods if you are working with one button at a time. You will need a using statement for the namespace the extension method is in.

Extension methods are a way of adding an instance method to an existing class.

see [MSDN - Extension Methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx)

eg:

```
public static class ButtonExtensions
{
    public static void SetVisibility(this Button button, Visibility visibility)
    {
       button.Visibility = visibility;
    }
}
```

usage:

```
public void Test()
{
    Button button = new Button();
    Visibility visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

    button.SetVisibility(visibility);

    //or
    ButtonExtensions.SetVisibility(button, visibility);
}
```